# Using Icinga 1 object configuration files with Icinga 2

Tags: icinga, icinga2

Icinga 2 introduced a new format for its object configuration files. Where Icinga 1 e.g. expected

```
define service {
    name my_service
# ...
}
```

Icinga 2 now expects

```
object Service "my_service" {
# ...
}
```

Is there a reliable automatic way for translating Icinga 1 to Icinga 2 object configuration files both in terms or syntax and semantics (or a way for directly using Icinga 1 object configuration files with Icinga 2)?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't just port your old config, re-think it and enjoy a clean config.

There is a whole doc guide to help you understand the differences: https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/23-migrating-from-icinga-1x/

What's really different from Icinga 1.x and Nagios:

- Notifications
- Command Parametrization
- Custom vars (now the get used)

Suggestions are always:

- Start with your hosts
- Think about templating
- Add vars to categorize your environment
- Add common services by apply
- Add notifications by apply

Comment: The point about rethinking the old config is well taken. I'm actively working on this, but am also interested in a migration tool for the intermediate term. (So of the old configs where auto-generated, so it is "kind of" hard to rethink those.)

Answer (score 0):

This solution here looks like it could do what you need:
 https://github.com/palli/icinga2/tree/master/tools/configconvert

Comment: Thx, I am still surprised though that Netways does not seem to provide anything like that as part of Icinga 2 itself.

Comment: There were two versios of such a migration script, none of them really helped with converting the objects in a reliable way. By "reliable" I refer to a configuration you can take care of, and use the good stuff, as in "apply rules" or conditions, functions, etc.